# Attempting to make a stopwatch using two 74hc161n chips with decoders and seven segments

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, circuit-analysis

I have been tasked with constructing a digital clock in my electronics class. I had a problem with multisim and had to change my design but now I can't figure out how to make these counters reset correctly. The problem I have is this circuit counts from 0-50 and then resets to 1. My least significant counter works fine, always from 0-9, but the most significant one counts from 0-5 and then instantly to 0 instead of waiting for another 9. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Two problems.

1) Connect your load inputs (A,B,C,D) to ground. Never, ever, leave CMOS inputs floating.

2) Make U4 a 3-input gate, and connect your U5 output to it, as well as the ENP input. What's happening is that your load input acts immediately. It is not gated with the enable inputs. So as soon as you hit 5, U4 goes low and the second counter resets on the next clock edge, rather than waiting 10 counts.

Comment: Thank you so much! That makes a lot of sense. I figured the rollover was happening immediately I just couldn't come up with a solution. And I of course am setting the abcd to ground in my pref board design haha. Thanks again!